# Why do binarySearch on list in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, data-structures, binary-search

I am not sure why List as a general data structure should have binary search algorithm given the list is sorted. Doesn't the `get` method which accepts the index traverse the List sequentially, at least for `List`'s subtype `LinkedList`? If so, I do not see any advantage of using binarySearch comparing with sequential comparison for `LinkedList`. Of course unless we restrict List to be `ArrayList` we can do binarySearch with more confidence.

Is my understanding correct? Thanks.

Comment: "given the list is sorted" - that's not a given.

Comment: I am just assuming that is true. Or we can always sort it first.

Comment: You are right, doing binary search on LinkedList is a bad idea.

Comment: Well, javadoc can be helpful here: *If the specified list does not implement the `RandomAccess` interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many ways to implement the `List`.  There's `ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, etc. in the standard Java libraries, and a host of other implementations beyond those ([VLists](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=vlist), circular buffers, skew binomial lists, [extendible arrays](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=extendible-array), [2-3 finger trees](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/FingerTree.pdf), etc.).  The idea behind providing binary search is that while not all List implementations support random access, the ones that do would benefit from having a generic implementation of binary search available so that the authors of each data structure don't have to reimplement it from scratch.  For example, if I implement a crazy new list structure that supports random access, if I implement the List interface I can automatically get a binary search available from the Collections class.

Interestingly, the `binarySearch` method is written such that it looks at the type of the `List` and sees whether it implements the `RandomAccess` interface before it actually does the binary search.  If the list doesn't implement `RandomAccess`, the instead of using a standard binary search, the method uses a modified binary search with iterators that is guaranteed to make at most O(n) iterations and O(log n) comparisons.  The idea is to keep track of where the last probe landed, then to walk forward or backward the appropriate number of steps to find the next probe location, etc.  The total work done is then at most n/2 + n/4 + n/8 + n/16 + ... = 2n, so in the worst-case it's only twice as bad as a worst-case linear search.

In short, providing a generic implementation of `binarySearch` doesn't always make it possible to quickly search a List for something, but for the structures that do support fast access it can make a huge difference and save a lot of implementer time.  Additionally, having the graceful degradation to the modified binary search that runs in O(n) time means that the implementation isn't ever going to be too much worse than a standard linear scan.

This reasoning is similar to the reasoning behind the design of the C++ algorithms, which operate on generic ranges of values.  The efficiency of these algorithms might be much worse than a specialized version of the algorithm on a per-data-structure basis, but having the general version available means that any new containers that support iterators can automatically have a lot of functionality available beyond just what's specified in the interface.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1. yes, what you said definitely helps. The fact that List has a binarySearch actually will hurt the newbies who think this will be faster without a second thought, but actually will be much slower when applied to a `LinkedList`. So it may confuse beginners rather than providing benefits. :)

Comment: Additionally, there's another possibility: what if your compareTo method is so slow that it actually outweighs the time it takes to traverse a LinkedList?

This isn't impossible, and in these cases Collections.binarySearch might actually win over a sequential search, even for LinkedList.

Comment: @LouisWasserman- That's an excellent point.  Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: +1 for a very good explanation.  I didn't realize that there was the fallback algorithm if the list isn't random access.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are right, if a list does not provide random access, which is the case for LinkedList, there is no any advantage. From the javadoc of `Collections.binarySearch()` :

> > This method runs in log(n) time for a "random access" list (which provides  near-constant-time positional access).  If the specified list does not implement the {@link RandomAccess} interface and is large, this method will do an iterator-based binary search that performs O(n) link traversals and O(log n) element comparisons.

So, the complexity in this case will be the same as in case of sequential comparison - O(n). Practically, I believe sequential comparison may be faster in many cases.

Comment: comment on your "the advantage is not big". I would say in many cases the actual performance of binarySearch is worse than sequential comparison even if the asymptotic complexity is the same.